# Tel Mithryn magic lift

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I have noticed a problem with the Tel Mithryn magic lift as Lydia goes up first but when I get to the top myself she is not there, but appears afterwards, coming up again in the lift but has been injured. I think she is jumping down again to be next to me before I get to the top.
Has anyone else had this problem and is there a way to prevent it without leaving Lydia behind?

Comment: Ok, it looks like the only solution is to leave Lydia next door with the Alchemist Vendor while I go up to talk with Neloth.
It’s a pity that the door script makes the companion always travel up first.

Comment: I had the even more irritating scenario of my follower pushing me straight off the ledge to my death as soon as I got to the top of the lift.  This happened three times before I shouted her across the room and ran deeper into the dwelling.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed in the latest [Unofficial Dragonborn Patch 2.0.3](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Dragonborn%20Patch%20Version%20History.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a bug in skyrim, and the only way to fix it is to download a mod called Unofficial Dragonborn Patch. If you're on PC I would recommend you download all of the patches, as it fixes a lot of the common bugs! :)

[Unofficial Dragonborn Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31083/)